# Exception from HRESULT: 0x8CE00001 when opening Visual Studio 2010 Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-designer

I'm trying to set up a new Windows Forms Application (C++/CLI) in Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7.  Every time I try to open up the Designer, it fails with this unhelpful error:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x8CE00001

Instances of this error (1)  

1.   Hide Call Stack 

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Designer.Interfaces.IVSMDCodeDomProvider.get_CodeDomProvider()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.CodeDomDocDataAdapter.get_Provider()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.CodeDomDocDataAdapter.get_CompileUnit()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

If I debug Visual Studio and break on CLR exceptions, it actually throws this exception first:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.dll
>
> Additional information: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

With this call stack:

```
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.VerifyNestedDocDataCompatible() + 0x15d bytes 
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Designer.Interfaces.IVSMDDesignerLoader.Initialize(object pSp, object pHier, int itemid, object punkDocData) + 0xb5 bytes  
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    vcpkg.dll!CVCFormEditorFactory::CreateEditorInstance()  + 0x2e49f bytes 
    msenv.dll!CVsUIShellOpenDocument::OpenSpecificEditor()  + 0x784 bytes   
    VCProject.dll!CVCFileNode::OpenSpecificEditor()  + 0xc6 bytes   
    VCProject.dll!CVCFileNode::OpenSpecificEditor()  + 0x3a bytes   
    VCProject.dll!CVCFileNode::DoOpenFile()  + 0x1fe bytes  
    VCProject.dll!CVCFileNode::DoDefaultAction()  + 0x5b bytes  
    VCProject.dll!CVCArchy::ExecCommand()  + 0x8c bytes 
    msenv.dll!CVsUIHierarchyBaseWin::ExecHierParentChain()  + 0x85 bytes    
    msenv.dll!CVsUIHierarchyBaseWin::WinExecCommand()  + 0x7d bytes 
    msenv.dll!CVsUIHierarchyBaseWin::ProcessLButtonDblClkMsg()  + 0xd8 bytes    
    msenv.dll!FnwpTVFixer()  + 0x76b49 bytes    
    user32.dll!_InternalCallWinProc@20()  + 0x23 bytes  
    user32.dll!_UserCallWinProcCheckWow@32()  + 0xb7 bytes  
    user32.dll!_DispatchMessageWorker@8()  + 0xed bytes 
    user32.dll!_DispatchMessageW@4()  + 0xf bytes   
    msenv.dll!ProcessMessage()  + 0x4d bytes    
    msenv.dll!CMsoCMHandler::EnvironmentMsgLoop()  + 0x87 bytes 
    msenv.dll!CMsoCMHandler::FPushMessageLoop()  + 0x79 bytes   
    msenv.dll!SCM::FPushMessageLoop()  + 0x8c bytes 
    msenv.dll!SCM_MsoCompMgr::FPushMessageLoop()  + 0x2a bytes  
    msenv.dll!CMsoComponent::PushMsgLoop()  + 0x28 bytes    
    msenv.dll!VStudioMainLogged()  + 0x22a bytes    
    msenv.dll!_VStudioMain()  + 0x78 bytes  
    devenv.exe!util_CallVsMain()  + 0xdb bytes  
    devenv.exe!CDevEnvAppId::Run()  + 0x693 bytes   
    devenv.exe!_WinMain@16()  + 0x9c bytes  
    devenv.exe!operator new[]()  + 0xb31c bytes 
    kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  + 0x12 bytes    
    ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x27 bytes   
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x1b bytes
```

This is with a clean, new project (**File → New → Project... → Visual C++ → CLR → Windows Forms Application**).  After I create a new project, opening up the autogenerated `Form1.h` results in the error instead of the Designer.  However, if I create a C# Windows Forms Application instead of C++/CLI, it works fine.

Any ideas on how I can solve this problem and open up the Designer?  I've tried all of the following to no avail:

- Reinstalling [VS 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75568aa6-8107-475d-948a-ef22627e57a5&displaylang=en)
- Running Windows Update, which installed two VS-related updates ("Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 (KB2736182)" and "Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (KB2764593)")
- Installing [KB2635973](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27130), which fixes a similar-looking issue
- Rebooting after installing the above
- Turning off all DirectX debugging/validation settings in the DirectX Control Panel
- Uninstalling anything with "Microsoft SQL Server Compact" in its name via the "Program and Features" control panel

I've found a few similar threads online ([one](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/684190/windows-forms-designer-fails-to-load-for-c-cli-project-error-0x8ce00001), [two](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcprerelease/thread/67d65d8d-db42-430f-aeb7-40925cb0c0c8), [three](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/51f26bc6-1e7d-4e34-8b0e-853b48aa1749)), but they've all been inconclusive or not worked for me.  I've not yet tried fully reinstalling Visual Studio, but I may have to try that next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much nuking and reinstalling, I believe this to have been a problem with a Visual Studio Extension.

Completely uninstalling Visual Studio (even with [`VS2010_Uninstall-RTM.ENU.exe /full /netfx`](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall)) and reinstalling it didn't help.  But, if I created a new Windows user, it worked fine for that user.  Similarly, if I nuked my `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config` registry keys (and their subkeys), it worked.

After painstakingly comparing my old registry (where it gave the error) with a fresh registry (where it worked) and reconciling them, the only differences that remained were related to a particular VS extension.  Since I no longer need that extension, I don't need its registry keys, so without them, the Designer is working as expected.

Comment: I can confirm that I had the same issue and it was related to VS extensions. I uninstalled all non-essentials from the extension manager, rebooted VS and the issue was gone.

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully fixed the problem by setting:

> tools -> options -> textEditor -> C++ -> Advanced -> "Disable DataBase"

back to **false** (when `DisableDataBase == true` the HRESULT error appears), than restarting VisualStudio.

Comment: Worked for me with VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error in VS2013

what resolved it for me was

- Deleting the Pre Compiled Header file
- Reopening VS using Run as Administrator
- Rebuilt the solution

Afterwards i was no longer receiving the error, hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue in Visual Studio 2012. My project was located in a Dropbox directory and the Exception from hresult 0x8ce00001 issue was there until I moved the project to my Desktop. I assume that Dropbox's versioning activities may have had something to do with the issue. I hope this might help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem only installing the SQL Server Compact 3.5.

Attention, maybe your project needs the version 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Build -> Clean Solution.
Close Visual Studio and reopen.
This resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but as the solution I found in VS 2017 is very simple, I decided to publish it. For me, this problem started when I switched from Debug X86 to Debug X64 and then back to X86. As I did not realize at what moment the problem came up, I wasted enormous time looking for the solution. But simply when I returned to Debug X64 the problem disappeared...